# intellij/maven (/checkstyle)

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Sitting in intellij community edition 11, I'd like to run checkstyle with exactly the options that maven will run it with. In fact, I'd be happy to just run a maven build of the module and get any checkstyle (or PMD (or whatever)) errors. I'm not seeing how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the steps in [this documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-maven-run-debug-configuration.html), create a new configuration for a maven goal and specify `checkstyle:checkstyle`. This can then be run from Run menu.

There could be other (better) ways, but this is based on my limited (first-time) experience with IDEA.

Comment: I've already got the first part, checkstyle is part of my normal build process in the validate phase. I'll go see if I can get Run to do the dirty work from here.